# Converting 3d euler angles to 2d

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, puzzle, classical-mechanics

I know the title might be a bit confusing but please hear me out.

I have built a 2 axis [motion simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_simulator) in my garage with the intent of having it emulate my RC airplane. Sounds pretty simple right? When my airplane rolls, my simulator rolls. When my airplane pitches, my simulator pitches. ect.

But here is the problem. The motion simulator is capable of continuous rotation in either axis (or both at the same time) but cannot yaw. This leads to some interesting scenarios which I cant figure out.

Imagine if the aircraft were to pitch 180 degrees, then yaw 180 degrees

[image]

Since the motion simulator can't yaw, this motion would result exactly the same as if the simulator were to only roll 180:
[image]

This makes it extremly difficult to calculate which axis I should be moving since, from the simulator's point of view, [180, 180, 0] = [0, 0, 180]  (in format [yaw, pitch, roll])

And it's not just this motion that is confusing. [180, 0, 180] = [0 ,180, 0]. Like such:

[image]

All this to say that if I'm given an angle such as [180, 180, 0], how do I know what angle to set my motion simulator to (remember that it is only two axis). This would be pretty simple if the simulator could "snap" to a rotation, but since it is mechanical it takes time to rotate. I can't immediately rotate the pitch to 180 and the roll to 180 from zero even though from a mathematical point of view it would end up having the same angle (ignoring yaw). If I tried, the rider would have a good two seconds of disorienting movement.

I know I'm missing something here, but I've been beating my head against this problem with no success. I probably did a terrible job explaining the issue (I have a very hard time putting thoughts into words) Just let me know if I can elaborate at all. Thank you!

If anyone is interested here is the build process of my motion simulator: link

Comment: I wonder if you're encountering gymbal lock. If so, I'd recommend you switch to using quaternions, if you can. Also, be aware that rotations in 3D are not commutative, though they are in 2D.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with quaternions, but my on-board gyro will output them. Is there a clever way to use them so I won't have to deal with gymbal lock?

Comment: You don't have to be clever with them, you just use them. The wiki page on quaternions, and the one on rotations with quaternions are both very good. Many programming languages have libraries for working with quaternions.

Comment: Right, but in the end I need to end up with two angles. One for pitch and one for roll.

Comment: How about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles